# MySQL Daemon failed to start on CentOS 6 Server

Tags: mysql, centos, centos6

Whenever I try to start the SQLD service I get MySQL Daemon Failed to Start. I infact tried to "start" the service by doing the following:

```
[root@www1 ~]# service mysqld restart
mysqld stopped:                                            [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
mysqld started:                                            [FAILED]
[root@www1 ~]#
```

In my MySQL error log isnt any information the last entry is:

```
170314  3:24:59 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

170314  3:24:59 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
170314  3:25:01 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 1605619  user: 'admin'

170314  3:25:01 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 1605617  user: 'admin'
170314  3:25:01 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 13  user: 'admin'

170314  3:25:06  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170314  3:25:08  InnoDB: Waiting for 35 pages to be flushed
170314  3:25:46  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 26624434202
170314  3:25:47 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

170314 03:25:50 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I've tried to start mysql in safemode

```
[root@www1 log]# mysqld_safe
170314 09:36:39 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
170314 09:36:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170314 09:36:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
[root@www1 log]#
```

SELinux is disabled on my centos maschine. Can anyone help me?
EDIT: There is no update last night.

Comment: Did your server update last night? I seem to be having similar issues at the moment...

Comment: [This problem has been solved here！](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941499/6516932)

Comment: If all above methods are not working, check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45727391/3286605](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45727391/3286605)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue is related to a broken update by Plesk.

Please read the article https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001906725 .

You can fix it by running this command:

`install -m 0700 -o mysql -g mysql -d /var/lib/mysql-files`

and start mysql

`service mysqld start`

Comment: Any other tries? I executed but nothing changes.

Answer (score 3):

```
    yum history
```

find the ID of the update

```
    yum history undo <id>
```

I just had this issue and this resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

**TIP**: It's  always a good idea to back up the directory `/var/lib/mysql` before executing trial commands in case you need to go back to an initial state.

If after executing the command in the marked answer your *mysqld* service still doesn't start make sure that the ownership of the directory (and sub directories) of `/var/lib/mysql` is **mysql:mysql** .

If they are not, to fix that do the following:

(I did this in CentOS , I had my ownership set to root:root).

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

After that the `service mysqld start` finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my CentOS server after running yum update.
I have no Plesk installed on it, but their article https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001906725 helped.

```
install -m 0700 -o mysql -g mysql -d /var/lib/mysql-files
```

Looks like mysql package in atomic repos is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43950190/4778754, The problem is caused by the conflict between the size you set in my.con file and actually the size of the file in data directory.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me. Run this command.

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Same problem occurred for me also, Then i tried above command in putty, Then mysql restarted successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Atomic fixed the issue:
https://forums.atomicorp.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=8535&p=44022#p44022